# Stub method in grails unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, grails, groovy

I have a unit test that does not seem to pass. :(

```
{
    given:
    Date currentDate = new Date()
    DateUtils.getCurrentDate() >> currentDate
    BigDecimal amount = 5
    long paymentMethodId = 4L
    Date fiveMinutesBeforeCurrentDate = new Date()

    use (TimeCategory) {
        fiveMinutesBeforeCurrentDate = currentDate-5.minutes
    }

    PaymentDetails details = Mock(PaymentDetails)
    PaymentDetails.findByIdAndAmountAndDateCreatedGreaterThanEquals(paymentMethodId, amount, fiveMinutesBeforeCurrentDate) >> details

    when:
    service.validatePaymentDetails(paymentMethodId, amount)

    then:
    thrown InvalidOperationException
}
```

The error always seems "No exception was thrown". The method `validatePaymentDetails` should throw an exception if the value of `details` is not null.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you saying that `validatePaymentDetails` invokes `fetchByIdAndAmountAndDateCreatedGreaterThanEquals` and if `fetchByIdAndAmountAndDateCreatedGreaterThanEquals` returns anything other than `null`, then `validatePaymentDetails` is supposed to throw an `InvalidOperationException`?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown i edited my code.. yeah, if there's a similar transaction within the last five minutes, it should throw the `InvalidOperationException`. But for some reason, there's something wrong with how i mocked it? It always stubs `null`

Comment: When your test invokes `validatePaymentDetails` that method is going to call `findByIdAndAmountAndDateCreatedGreaterThanEquals` in that same class and the mock won't be in play at all.  You have mocked the `PaymentDetails` object, not the service method.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Sorry. I don't get it. Can you help me? It's my first time with grails. I actually work with Java and Spock but this certain module has a bug that I have to fix lol :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a service like this:

```
class PaymentService {

    void validatePaymentDetails(long paymentMethodId, BigDecimal amount) {
        if(PaymentDetails.findByIdAndAmountAndDateCreatedGreaterThanEquals(paymentMethodId, amount, new Date()) != null) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException()
        }
    }
}
```

A unit test that would make sure that `InvalidOperationException` is thrown whenever `PaymentDetails.findByIdAndAmountAndDateCreatedGreaterThanEquals` returns something other than `null` could look like this:

```
import grails.testing.gorm.DataTest
import grails.testing.services.ServiceUnitTest
import spock.lang.Specification

class PaymentServiceSpec extends Specification implements ServiceUnitTest<PaymentService>, DataTest{

    @Override
    Class[] getDomainClassesToMock() {
        [PaymentDetails]
    }

    void "test payment details validation"() {
        given:
        BigDecimal amount = 5
        long paymentMethodId = 4L

        GroovySpy(PaymentDetails, global: true)

        def details = new PaymentDetails()
        1 * PaymentDetails.findByIdAndAmountAndDateCreatedGreaterThanEquals(_, _, _) >> details

        when:
        service.validatePaymentDetails(paymentMethodId, amount)

        then:
        thrown InvalidOperationException
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for this! It was able to help me understand. But I switched up the approach (create the entity) but it still returns null. if you're still interested to help, I posted another question :) Thank you so much!